# How can set ViewBag to Html.ActionLink string link text argumants?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and write this code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(@item.BookName, "Item", new {parentPartId = 0})
}
```

but in this segment:

```
@item.BookName
```

get this error:
[image]

How can i Solve that?thanks all.

this is my controller code:

```
    List<StoreList> myList=new List<StoreList>();
    foreach (var VARIABLE in query_BookItem)
    {
        StoreList myClass = new StoreList();
        myClass.BookName = VARIABLE.BookName;
        myClass.BookText = VARIABLE.BookText;
        myList.Add(myClass);

    }
    ViewBag.MyList = myList;
```

Comment: Cast it to what ever the type in `MyList` is (`ViewBag` is dynamic and you cannot use `dynamic` in a `HtmlHelper`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for pay attention to my problem,please review my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewBag` is `dynamic`, and you cannot use `dynamic` in `HtmlHelper` methods. You need to first cast the item to `StoreList` (assumes you have included a `@using` statement in the view to point to the assembly that `StoreList` is in)

```
@foreach (StoreList item in ViewBag.MyList)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.BookName, "Item", new {parentPartId = 0})
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList as List<StoreList>)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.BookName, "Item", new {parentPartId = 0})
}
```

or

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(((StoreList)item).BookName, "Item", new {parentPartId = 0})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.BookName, "Item", new {parentPartId = 0})
```

to this and solve:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Item", "Store", new {parentPartId = 0})">@item.BookName</a>
```